# ValueError: Trying to share variable rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/basic_lstm_cell/kernel

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, lstm

This it the code:

```
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, seq_len_1, 1], name='X')
labels = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, alpha_size], name='labels')

rnn_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(512)
m_rnn_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([rnn_cell] * 3, state_is_tuple=True)
pre_prediction, state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(m_rnn_cell, X, dtype=tf.float32)
```

This is full error:

> **ValueError:** Trying to share variable rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/basic_lstm_cell/kernel, but specified shape (1024, 2048) and found shape (513, 2048).

I'm using a GPU version of tensorflow.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I encountered a similar problem when I upgraded to v1.2 (tensorflow-gpu). 
Instead of using `[rnn_cell]*3`, I created 3 `rnn_cells` (stacked_rnn) by a loop (so that they don't share variables) and fed `MultiRNNCell` with `stacked_rnn` and the problem goes away. I'm not sure it is the right way to do it.

```
stacked_rnn = []
for iiLyr in range(3):
    stacked_rnn.append(tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(num_units=512, state_is_tuple=True))
MultiLyr_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell(cells=stacked_rnn, state_is_tuple=True)
```

Answer (score 14):

An official TensorFlow tutorial recommends this way of multiple LSTM network definition:

```
def lstm_cell():
  return tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(lstm_size)
stacked_lstm = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell(
    [lstm_cell() for _ in range(number_of_layers)])
```

You can find it here: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/recurrent

Actually it it almost the same approach that Wasi Ahmad and Maosi Chen suggested above but maybe in a little bit more elegant form.

Answer (score 6):

I guess it's because your RNN cells on each of your 3 layers share the same input and output shape.

On layer 1, the input dimension is 513 = 1(your x dimension) + 512(dimension of the hidden layer) for each timestamp per batch.

On layer 2 and 3, the input dimension is 1024 = 512(output from previous layer) + 512 (output from previous timestamp).

The way you stack up your MultiRNNCell probably implies that 3 cells share the same input and output shape.

I stack up MultiRNNCell by declaring two separate types of cells in order to prevent them from sharing input shape

```
rnn_cell1 = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(512)
run_cell2 = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(512)
stack_rnn = [rnn_cell1]
for i in range(1, 3):
    stack_rnn.append(rnn_cell2)
m_rnn_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell(stack_rnn, state_is_tuple = True)
```

Then I am able to train my data without this bug.
I'm not sure whether my guess is correct, but it works for me. Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue using Google Colab's Jupiter notebook. I resolved the issue by restarting the kernel and then rerunning the code.

Comment: Once you restart the kernel you just need to rerun the imports again.