# pandas read_csv not recognizing \t in tab delimited file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm trying to read in the following tab separated data into pandas:
test.txt:

```
col_a\tcol_b\tcol_c\tcol_d
4\t3\t2\t1  
4\t3\t2\t1
```

I import test.txt as follows:

```
pd.read_csv('test.txt',sep='\t')
```

The resulting dataframe has 1 column.  The \t is not recognized as tab.

If I replace \t with a 'keyboard tab' the file is parsed correctly. I also tried replacing '\t with \t and /t and didn't have any luck.

Thanks in advance for your help.
Omar

PS: Screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/AykQl.jpg

Comment: Please provide a *reproducible example*. Using the exact data you gave, and the exact same code, I'm getting a data-frame with a shape `(2,4)`. Do you actually have *tabs* in your csv? Or is it delimited by literally the characters `"\t"`?

Comment: So you just pasted the snippet above into a text file called 'test.txt' and ran:  
**import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv('test.txt',sep='\t')**

Maybe the problem is with my text editor?

Comment: Does your text-editor actually *show the characters `'\t'`*? Because then you **don't have tabs**.

Comment: No, the text editor doesn't actually display the \t as a tab

Comment: Then they aren't tabs. If you want to put tabs in your file, you should use the tab button. `\t` is a Python (and many other languages) escape sequence. Your text editor is going to assume you mean the actual characters `"\"` followed by `"t"`

Comment: No, it doesn't. It is an [**escape sequence**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal#Escape_sequences). This is for your convenience for writing source code, it's *Python that interprets it as a tab*.  The same way in Python `[]` mean a list, but in your text-editor it is just square brackets...

Comment: Ah I see.  The reason I used \t because I was trying to find and replace the old delimiter with a tab.  Thanks!

Answer (score 23):

The `\t` in your file is an actual backslash followed by a `t`.  It is **not** a `tab`.  You're going to have to use some escape characters on your `sep` parameter.

```
pd.read_csv('test.txt', sep=r'\\t', engine='python')

   col_a  col_b  col_c  col_d
0      4      3      2      1
1      4      3      2      1
```

Or

```
pd.read_csv('test.txt', sep='\\\\t', engine='python')

   col_a  col_b  col_c  col_d
0      4      3      2      1
1      4      3      2      1
```

---

[**response to comment**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4780104/2336654)

The `r` is indicating that it is a raw string and special characters should be interpreted the raw character.  That is why in one solution I indicated that the string was raw and only had two backslashes.  In the other, I had to escape each backslash with another backslash, leaving four backslashes.

Comment: This is not working for me on `os/x high sierra` with `python 2.7.3`

Comment: in my case this works: pd.read_csv(path, sep='\\t', engine='python'), without mentioning r befor separator(python 3.7/ipython)