# pandas python read_csv not recognizing \t in tab delimiter

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm trying to read in the following tab separated data into pandas:
test.csv:

col_a\tcol_b\tcol_c\tcol_d
4\t3\t2\t1
4\t3\t2\t1

I tried import test.csv in different ways as follows but not success:

```
pd.read_csv('test.csv',delimeter='\t')
pd.read_csv('test.csv',sep='\t')
pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep=r'\\t', engine='python')
```

The resulting dataframe has 1 column. The \t is not recognized as tab.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("filename.csv", '\t')
print(df)

Answer (score 0):

I think the r'' suffix is used in the wrong way.

try:

`pd.read_csv('test.csv',sep='\\t')`
or
`pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep=r'\t')`

Here an olt topic:
[python pandas read_csv not recognizing \t in tab delimited file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45443406/python-pandas-read-csv-not-recognizing-t-in-tab-delimited-file)

Comment: I tried this way but the result is not constant